# What is the meaning of this method calcWrappedOffset ()

Tags: queue, rx-java

A method in a queue, offer I don't quite understand the effect of this method
：

```
  @Override
public boolean offer(final T e) {
    if (null == e) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null is not a valid element");
    }
    // local load of field to avoid repeated loads after volatile reads
    final AtomicReferenceArray<Object> buffer = producerBuffer;
    final long index = lpProducerIndex();
    final int mask = producerMask;
    final int offset = calcWrappedOffset(index, mask);
    .......
 }
```

calcWrappedOffset() method:

```
   private static int calcWrappedOffset(long index, int mask) {
    return calcDirectOffset((int)index & mask);
}
private static int calcDirectOffset(int index) {
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What is that you don't understand?

This is from the [`SpscLinkedArrayQueue`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/2.x/src/main/java/io/reactivex/internal/queue/SpscLinkedArrayQueue.java#L72) I presume which uses circular buffers with power of 2 size. Due to being power of 2, wrapping the index around requires a simple and fast binary 'and' with the `mask = size - 1` value instead of the heavy modulo operator.

The original JCTools version allowed spanning out items in the array to reduce the false-sharing effects but RxJava decided to not support that in order to reduce memory consumption, hence the `calcDirectOffset` returning the unaltered index.